# Merge and remove rows with blanks in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the data as below:

```
IDS_DEV Teradata IDS_DEV Data_Waive LEG_TX     Account Transaction No  XDR
IDS_DEV Teradata IDS_DEV Data_Waive LEG_TX     Data Transaction    No  XDR
IDS_DEV Teradata IDS_DEV Data_Waive LEG_TX                                
IDS_DEV Teradata IDS_DEV Data_Waive LEG_TX     Job Transaction     No  XDR
IDS_DEV Teradata IDS_DEV Data_Waive TRANS_AM   Account Transaction     DEG
IDS_DEV Teradata IDS_DEV Data_Waive TRANS_AM                       Yes    
IDS_DEV Teradata IDS_DEV Data_Waive TRA_EFF_DT Account Transaction     PDR
IDS_DEV Teradata IDS_DEV Data_Waive TRA_EFF_DT                     No  PDR
```

[image]

Here the column HDFT can have multiple values, N_Identity can have Yes or No and Class will have one particular value.

Now, for the same column group LEG_TX where there are multiple values for HDFT i just want all the rows except the blank row.
Also, i want to combine the rows into one for Trans_AM and TRA_EFF_DT into one row.

Below is the result i want:
[image]

```
DB  DBMS    Schema  Table   Column  HDFT    N_Identity  Class
IDS_DEV Teradata    IDS_DEV Data_Waive  LEG_TX  Account Transaction No  XDR
IDS_DEV Teradata    IDS_DEV Data_Waive  LEG_TX  Data Transaction    No  XDR
IDS_DEV Teradata    IDS_DEV Data_Waive  LEG_TX  Job Transaction No  XDR
IDS_DEV Teradata    IDS_DEV Data_Waive  TRANS_AM    Account Transaction Yes DEG
IDS_DEV Teradata    IDS_DEV Data_Waive  TRA_EFF_DT  Account Transaction No  PDR
```

I am able to achieve the second case using Max(case..) but in doing so the first requirement is not getting met.

Not adding the text data as the format is getting messed up.

Thanks.

[Updated]Adding another Sample:

[image]

Output:
[image]

The N_Identity **can be either** Yes or No for a particular column.

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted code. This page may help you: http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-flat-file.htm

Comment: Okay ..let me check this.

Comment: Is this fine? Can i remove the images now?

Comment: The first table has not header and you may "ASCII Table-ize" it for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to meet your second requirement, I will focus on the first:

You can do

```
WHERE Column != 'LEG_TX' OR HDFT != ''
```

to filter out rows with emty HDFT which also have Column == LEG_TX.

Just combine this with the solution you have for your second requirement.

Comment: That's just a sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option; useful code is from line #13 onwards.

```
SQL> with test (col, hdft, n_identity, class) as
  2    (select 'leg_tx'  , 'account transaction  ', 'no', 'xdr' from dual union all
  3     select 'leg_tx'  , 'data transaction'     , 'no', 'xdr' from dual union all
  4     select 'leg_tx'  , null                   , null, null  from dual union all
  5     select 'leg_tx'  , 'job transaction'      , 'no', 'xdr' from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select 'trans_am', 'account transaction'  , null, 'deg' from dual union all
  8     select 'trans_am', null                   , 'yes', null from dual union all
  9     --
 10     select 'tra_eff_dt', 'account transaction', null, 'pdr' from dual union all
 11     select 'tra_eff_dt', null                 , 'no', 'pdr' from dual
 12    ),
 13  temp as
 14    (select t.*,
 15       case when hdft is null and n_identity is null and class is null then -1
 16            when hdft is not null and n_identity is not null and class is not null then 1
 17            else 0
 18       end flag
 19     from test t
 20    )
 21  select col, hdft, n_identity, class
 22    from temp
 23    where flag = 1
 24  union all
 25  select col, max(hdft), max(n_identity), max(class)
 26    from temp
 27    where flag = 0
 28    group by col;

COL        HDFT                  N_I CLA
---------- --------------------- --- ---
leg_tx     account transaction   no  xdr
leg_tx     data transaction      no  xdr
leg_tx     job transaction       no  xdr
trans_am   account transaction   yes deg
tra_eff_dt account transaction   no  pdr

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query:

```
select * from Y
where HDFT is not null and N_Identity is not null and class1 is not null
union all
select DB,DBMS, SCHEME, TABLE1, COLUMN1, max(HDFT), max(N_Identity), max(class1) from Y 
where Column1 in ('TRANS_AM','TRA_EFF_DT')
group by 
DB, DBMS, SCHEME, TABLE1, COLUMN1
```

[image]

Comment: The data i have pasted is just a sample data and i have other columns as well in the table. Can we have a more generalized query

Answer (score 0):

As long as I understand your data set correctly, this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT * FROM
   (
        SELECT COL, MAX(HDFT) as HDFT, MAX(N_Identity) as N_Identity, MAX(CLS) as CLS  
        FROM table_1
        GROUP BY COL
   )a 

  UNION

  SELECT COL, HDFT, N_IDENTITY, CLS FROM table_1

)b

WHERE HDFT IS NOT NULL
AND N_IDENTITY IS NOT NULL
AND CLS IS NOT NULL
```

To add more columns, all you have to do is add them to the two SELECT statements and the WHERE clause at the end (3 places).  For example,

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT * FROM
   (
        SELECT COL, MAX(HDFT) as HDFT, MAX(N_Identity) as N_Identity, MAX(CLS) as CLS, MAX(COL_5) as COL_5, MAX(COL_6) as COL_6
        FROM table_1
        GROUP BY COL
   )a 

  UNION

  SELECT COL, HDFT, N_IDENTITY, CLS, COL_5, COL_6 FROM table_1

)b

WHERE HDFT IS NOT NULL
AND N_IDENTITY IS NOT NULL
AND CLS IS NOT NULL
AND COL_5 IS NOT NULL
AND COL_6 IS NOT NULL
```

This will work as long as N_IDENTITY, CLASS, and subsequent columns only ever have 1 value per COLUMN.  If there exists data like:

```
COLUMN  HDFT                 N_IDENTITY  CLASS
------  -------------------  ----------  -----
LEG_TX  Account Transaction  No          XDR
LEG_TX  Data Transaction     Yes         XDR
LEG_TX  Job Transaction      No          XDR
```

, where there are multiple N_IDENTITY values for the same COLUMN value, then the above query will not produce the results you are after.

Comment: Thanks bk_32. Let me check this and get back to you.

Comment: The provided query is not working for the added sample.

Comment: Not working how?  Can you provide the query that you tried exactly, along with the error message you received?